# список в с# и картинки

Tags: c#

Как в список добавить картинки на одну строку? 
[image: Пример]

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="audioView" SelectionMode="Extended"
         Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Tag="{Binding url}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Простите, а какой именно? C# или XAML? и какую именно часть кода надо показать?

Comment: Окей, для начала — ту часть XAML, которая отвечает за внешний вид Item'а в списке.

Comment: @VladD 
<ListBox
            x:Name="audioView"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
SelectionMode="Extended"
Background="Transparent"
Foreground="Black" Margin="30,-0.333,8,0.25" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"
                               Tag="{Binding url}" 
                               Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" FontFamily="Kunstler Script"/> </DataTemplate> </ListBox.ItemTemplate> </ListBox>

Comment: @VladD Простите, что так уродливо, просто тут ограничение по знакам.

Comment: Вот, чтобы понятнее было))
(https://5zujqw-ch3301.files.1drv.com/y3pNfDGrdsUHb7OgKBfU8sf7I_QDGiD6fXJyZJipRVQTGLO6tlpOQ7N0G0APv55ePYvXtkz0I4cJY_1ByY-l6usZnN1eCxUG3Hr-SSxmQ_3pQHWJfYJ5LKZVcRKKneqLvgxOYx-hLaZEffbSmJdgKp9s26OyVVflQo_NBY7Y5EUzpA/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B91.jpg?psid=1)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно ничего сложного нет, просто допишите в DataTemplate-е

```
<DataTemplate>
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image Source="{Binding Image}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Tag="{Binding url}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" FontFamily="Kunstler Script"/> 
 </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Соответственно Image поле надо определить во ViewModel

Comment: Спасибо!)))))))

Comment: а может вы сможете мне подсказать, как (каким методом) можно загрузить файл (а именно аудио-файл) с вконтакте?

Comment: Нет. Надо посмотреть на API сайта, что он позволяет с собой делать и какую информацию выдает на странице. Или попросту "вскрыть" приложение, которое уже этим занимается.

Comment: Просто на сайте ВК есть так сказать небольшой туториал. Я смог сделать запрос только на поиск музыки, а вот на загрузку там нет такого. Точнее на загрузку есть, но на загрузку на сайт, а вот на устройство нет( 
Но спасибо, что помогли с картинкой)))

Comment: @CocaineSnow, Вот `Api` для `Vk.Net` https://github.com/vknet/vk. А вот то что вас интересует https://vknet.github.io/vk/audio/get/

Comment: @Lightness спасибо!))